# Why is my PHP JSON outputting numbered indexes?

Tags: php, json

My code is outputting the JSON as arrays, not lists. Maybe I'm just confused by the way PHP creates JSON arrays or lists.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$data = $json['data'];

$cities = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $val) {

    $city = $val['city'];
    $region = $val['region'];
    $district = $val['district'];
    $combined = array(
        $city => array(
            array('city' => $city), 
            array('region' => $region), 
            array('district' => $district)
    ));

    if (!in_array($combined, $cities)) {

        array_push($cities, $combined);

    }

}

$result = json_encode(array('cities'=>$cities, 'branches'=>$data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Output

```
{
  "cities": [
    {
      "City 1": [
        {
          "city": "City 1"
        },
        {
          "region": "Region 1"
        },
        {
          "district": "District 1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "City 2": [
        {
          "city": "City 2"
        },
        {
          "region": "Region 2"
        },
        {
          "district": "District 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

If I then use `$cityCount = count($data['cities']);` on the created JSON file, I receive `0`.

The output should, imo be without square brackets

```
{
  "cities": {
      "City 1": {
        "city": "City 1",
        "region": "Region 1",
        "district": "District 1"
      },
      "City 2": {
        "city": "City 2",
        "region": "Region 2",
        "district": "District 2"
      },
      "City 3": {
        "city": "City 3",
        "region": "Region 3",
        "district": "District 3"
      },
      "City 4": {
        "city": "City 4",
        "region": "Region 4",
        "district": "District 4"
      }
  }
}
```

so that I can later use ie. `$data['cities']['City 1']['region']`.
Then count the number of city entries.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url); // URL of the above output

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$cityCount = count($data['cities']);
```

Why is the output creating objects inside arrays, when each array has defined key/value pairs?

Comment: The `{"key": {}, {}, {}}` is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you want, is not valid json.

However, it seems that is not really want you are looking for: In order to access the data as you want to, you should change:

```
$combined = array(
    $city => array(
        array('city' => $city), 
        array('region' => $region), 
        array('district' => $district)
));
```

to:

```
$combined = array(
    $city => array('city' => $city, 
                   'region' => $region, 
                   'district' => $district,
));
```

Now you will have all 3 items as keys on the third level.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed the output I need. Although `$cityCount = count($data['cities']);` doesn't work in this format either, is `count` not the correct way to count the number of indexes in `cities`?

Comment: @Fid I assume you mean `$result['cities']`. And no, you cannot use `count()` there; the result of `json_encode()` is a string and the only meaningful number you can get from it is its length. If you want to count the number of cities, you have to decode it to an array first, then you can count it. Note that the same applies to the way you want to access the data, you can only use that after decoding to an array, you cannot access anything directly from the string.

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the counting part of the script. I didn't make clear that the script is reading one json file, correcting the format of the city/region/district, then saving it. The count reads the saved file.

Comment: @Fid That is really another question as the `cities` key in your generated array is clear from the code, but the `cities` key from your input is unknown and unrelated to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is

```
$url = 'http://www.something.com/jason.json'; // Get data from public json file

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$data = $json['data']; // The actual data is in the 'data' object

$cities = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $val) { // City, region, district are nested in numbered objects

    $city = $val['city'];
    $region = $val['region'];
    $district = $val['district'];
    $combined = array(
        'city' => $city, 
        'region' => $region, 
        'district' => $district,
    );

    if (!in_array(array($city => $combined), $cities)) {

        $cities[$city] = $combined; // Add the $combined value array to $cities with the $city as the key

    }

}

$result = json_encode(array('cities'=>$cities), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Using `array_push($cities, $combined);` creates objects with numbered keys in the final json, whereas `$cities[$city] = $combined;` uses `$city` as the key, thus making it possible to use the actual city name in future searches through the json data.

Then save the result.

```
// continued

$saveName = 'localdirectory/new.json'; // Let's save the parsed json

file_put_contents($saveName, $result);
```

And finally we can check how many cities we saved to the new file

```
// continued

$newUrl = 'http://www.example.com/localdirectory/new.json';

$newJson = file_get_contents($newUrl);

$newData = json_decode($newJson, true);

$cityCount = count($data['cities']);
```

`count($data['cities']);` works in @jeroen's answer as well, `count` doesn't care whether the keys are numbers or strings.